# How did Iran mitigate the effect of the SWIFT sanctions on them?

Tags: international-relations, iran, sanctions, banking

It seems to me although Iran faced hash sanctions with SWIFT ban in 2012 and again in 2018, their GDP took a hit and dropped for two years and but rebounded again (even through Covid). From the chart it seems that Iran might have found ways to make the SWIFT sanctions (remember they also suffered from their sanctions like travel ban and oil export ban) less effective on them. I wonder how Iran mitigated the effect of the SWIFT sanctions.

[Source](https://tradingeconomics.com/iran/gdp#:%7E:text=GDP%20in%20Iran%20averaged%20164.41,4.20%20USD%20Billion%20in%201960.)

[image: The GDP of Iran since 2012]

Comment: I may confirm with research, but I suspect that this was done by using means other than wire transfers such as cash, commodity barters including gold, and Iranian currency denominated transactions (just as all banks did before wire transfers were invented).

Comment: I would not call having half the GDP much mitigation. Other than that, the Q is more or less a duplicate of https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/69748/how-is-iran-sustaining-its-economy

Comment: "less effective"? The change really isn't very pronounced. Maybe 10% less effective.

Comment: @Fizz Compared with the linked thread, my question is more focused on the finance part. By "mitigation" I meant Iran was able to rebound from the sanctions.

Comment: "rebound" This is not a pronounced rebound though. It could even be just natural fluctuation. Maybe next year there is a rebound from the rebound.

Comment: the bar chart mimics the price of oil for the same period, how do we know it shows any effects of sanctions?

Comment: Is it possible to make sure that the drop in GPD has been due to SWIFT and oil sanctions? If it was "totally" due to that, again it wouldn't start to thrive event hough the sanctions aren't lifted. On the other hand experts say that "sanctions loose their effectiveness after 2-4 years" (due to several reasons), so this isn't surprising that a country like Iran which is sanctioned more than 43 years can find a way to bend and bypass them, especially that Iran has allies like China and the rest that still buy its oil. (The bad economic situation has another reasons prior to sanctions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among other things:

1. Barter trade e.g. [with Sri Lanka they are swapping tea and debt](https://www.forbes.com/sites/dominicdudley/2021/12/23/iran-agrees-to-swap-tea-for-debt-reviving-barter-trade-to-avoid-sanctions/), [with the EU they are a member of a barter system called the INSTEX](https://www.voanews.com/a/middle-east_six-european-countries-join-barter-system-iran-trade/6180273.html),  [with Pakistan they are swapping oil for food items](https://www.tehrantimes.com/news/467213/Iran-Pakistan-reach-barter-trade-agreement).
2. Sanction evading exports - oil export is sanctioned. so, they are exporting petroleum byproducts e.g. lubricant, methanol, wax, etc.
3. Oil smuggling network - they have created a widespread oil smuggling network through which they can sell oil.

Ref: [How is Iran sustaining its economy?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/69758/32479)

Answer (score 0):

By [shipping dollars in suitcases](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-iran-dollars-exclusive-idUSKBN0LS1LV20150224), diplomatic pouches, and even in vodka boxes. Which sometimes [get stolen](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2020/12/25/1m-of-iranian-cash-stashed-in-vodka-box-stolen-from-russian-foreign-ministry-a72481).

Comment: Whoever DV this probably doesn't understand what SWIFT is. The accepted answer addresses the broader sanctions.